# Is there an English term for a person whose in favor (or against) an affidavit is made?

Tags: terminology

A (affiant) signs an affidavit where he/she declares that in order to cover his/her living costs, he/she has been receiving some money from B.

What term would best describe person B which could also be used in other contexts where money is not necessarily an element?

Comment: The named party?

Comment: guarantor? . . .

Comment: What's wrong with any synonym of "giver"? Like "donor"?

Comment: It could be 'party to...' and 'party against...'